# Scheduled SQL Job Not Running

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I created a SQL Job to re-organize all indexes at 2AM every day. When I check in the interface the job is due to run. However the job is not being run. I've tried checking the table msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules the job does not have a next_run_date or next_run_time.

Is there any reason why this would be happening? Am I checking in the wrong place?

[Job Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlrLu.png)
[Job Schedule Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9Ur.png)

Comment: Please confirm that your Job and all of its components are enabled, since you can disable a schedule and have a job enabled.

Comment: Yes the schedule is enabled.